# Check if date is n years old

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

I have a variable $date with format yyyy-mm-dd and I would like to check if it is exactly 1 year, 2 years (and so on) old.

That's what I tried so far:

```
dates=$(echo $date | cut -c6-10)
todays=$(date +"%m-%d")
if [ $todays == $dates ]; then
        echo "$path;$date;$time;$gps" >>$databasematch
else
        :
fi
```

Comment: and does it work? What problems do you face?

Comment: I edited the question. New solution that works, but it's not very elegant. Is there any other solution to compare the two dates? I'd like the comparison to be numerical, not with strings.

Comment: The question is out of line with the title. Please edit. Also, it's quite frustrating when you're changing the core of the question like this...

Comment: I am sorry about that! what do you suggest for the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the variables `$today` and `$date` holds today's date and the date that you'd like the check, respectively.

There is no need to convert the dates to second resolution, and you never subtract or add anything from/to any date in the comparison. Moreover, GNU date will know today's date (so `$today` can be removed), and the quoting is a bit messy.

Here's a version that checks whether `$then_date` is one year ago (GNU date is called `gdate` on my system):

```
then_date="2019-09-17"

if [[ $( gdate -d "now -1 year" +"%Y-%m-%d" ) == "$then_date" ]]; then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

If you wanted the number of years between the dates, you may first compare the date without the year, and then just output the year difference:

```
if [[ $( gdate +"%m%d" ) == $( gdate -d "$then_date" +"%m%d" ) ]]; then
    now_year=$( gdate +"%Y" )
    then_year=$( gdate -d "$then_date" +"%Y" )

    printf "'%s' is today, but %d years ago\n" \
        "$then_date" "$(( now_year - then_year ))"

else
    echo "Not same day"
fi
```

**EDIT**: The question changed. Now it asks if there's a better way of doing

```
dates=$(echo $date | cut -c6-10)
todays=$(date +"%m-%d")
if [ $todays == $dates ]; then
        echo "$path;$date;$time;$gps" >>$databasematch
else
        :
fi
```

Yes, there is:

```
now_day=$( gdate +"%m%d" )

echo "$date" | 
while read then_date; do
    then_day=$( gdate -d "$then_date" +"%m%d" )
    if [[ "$now_day" == "$then_day" ]]; then
        echo "$path;$date;$time;$gps"
    fi
done >$databasematch
```

This avoids reading lots of data into a variable if you're planning to replace the `echo "$date"` bit with anything that generates dates.

Comment: Can I nest the while in another while?

Comment: @giovi Sure... um, doing what?

Comment: There is a while read that reads a csv file and extracts for each line four variables separated by a semicolon.

Comment: @giovi Go on... I haven't got much to work with here. You would probably have to change the redirect into `$databasematch` from `>` to `>>` if you're executing the code several times, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: The part of script that is written in the question (which is basically two variables and an `if`) is nested into `while read path date time gps; do`. If you change the `if` with a `while`, will it work?

Comment: @giovi replace `$then_date` in my code with `$date`, and the `read`-loop with your `read`-loop. Is this what you mean? I don't think you need to nest more than that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41399/discussion-between-giovi321-and-kusalananda).